# How to rewrite an URL like this (localhost/mvc/public/index.php?url=watch?v=ohGXBKUkK4c)?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

How to rewrite an URL from this

```
localhost/mvc/public/index.php?url=watch?v=ohGXBKUkK4c
```

to this

```
localhost/mvc/public/watch?v=ohGXBKUkK4c
```

and put that `watch?v=ohGXBKUkK4c` into my variable `$theurl`?

BTW I'm using PHP.
I hope that you can help me, thanks.

Comment: URL rewriting is usually done in the server configuration, not in PHP.

Comment: When you say _rewrite_, do you mean a URL rewrite using the .htaccess, or do you want to do a string replacement, or what?